# Clean Debian install: User Manager unit failed state?

Tags: debian, systemd, users, selinux

I've got a fresh Debian 10 install (I only added SSH and SELinux, installed per the Debian docs) on a VPS that runs fine, but when I do `systemctl status` it lists a failed unit `user@1001.service`.

Investigating further, the log says:

```
PAM failed: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
Failed to set up PAM session: Operation not permitted
Failed at step PAM spawning /lib/systemd/systemd: Operation not permitted
Failed with result 'protocol'.
Failed to start User Manager for UID 1001.
```

This doesn't seem to provide much specific info. It looks like a random failed login attempt. But when I look at a CentOS server I've got running, it doesn't have failed systemd units for failed login attempts, so this behavior strikes me as odd. Shouldn't it fail silently, or am I missing some specific setting/config?

BTW, when I do `systemctl reset-failed` the failed unit goes away and stays away, until another failed attempt is recorded and it shows up as a new id, ie `user@1002.service`.

Comment: Check is the failures persist if you put SELinux into permissive mode.

Comment: Yes! Of course, inexplicable, vague errors = SELinux... But now I can't seem to find what I should allow in order to get rid of these errors. I've tried auditing for systemd, but although this is indeed mentioned in the log, if I try to create a module for it to import, it stays blank. Any ideas?